# Getting Dates In Range Into Table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have a calendar table that shows all dates from 01/01/2015 to 12/31/2016, essentially the calendar shows the date and isworkday.  I need to be able to pass a begindate and enddate to a stored procedure and insert all the dates that are in the range in a table.  So for example something like this

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[DateRangeTest]
(
  @begindate date
  ,@enddate date
)
As

Set @begindate = '01/01/2016'
Set @enddate = '01/31/2016'
```

Now here is where my lack of knowledge comes to play, how can I then take all the dates in that range that are flagged as workdays from my workcalendar table and insert those specific dates into a temp table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guessing at column names:

```
INSERT #temp(dateColumn) 
  SELECT dateColumn
  FROM dbo.WorkCalendar
  WHERE IsWorkDay = 1
  AND dateColumn >= @begindate
  AND dateColumn < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @enddate);
```

Also please try to avoid regional formats like `m/d/y`. These will bite you in the end, because someone will run your code on a server with different language or regional settings, and it will be interpreted as `d/m/y`. See [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries). Also, for information on why I didn't use `BETWEEN`, see [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) It may work for the `date` data type, but I'd rather be consistent than surprised.